# Dictionary containing an array of strings as value

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to have a string array as the value in a dictionary? I need to save the description (Hour2) as the key and as value being able to access both the price (elements_PR(4)) and the time offset (1). Is there a good way to do that?

```
Dim pr_val(2) As String
Dim PR As New Dictionary(Of String, pr_val)

PR.Add("Hour2", {elements_PR(4), "1"})
```

Comment: If you fix the declaration i don't see any problem `Dim PR As New Dictionary(Of String, string())`. Well, of course elements_PR(4) is a string right?

Comment: Dim PR As New Dictionary(Of String, String()) and PR.Add("Hour1", {"",""}) doesn't work either. The error: Comma, ')' or valid expression continuation expected.

Comment: It works for me.  It sounds like you are missing a parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why you can't do it - you could also use values of type Tuple(Of String, String), if the number of elements is fixed in advance - in this case, 2. It'd be easier to perform comparisons on, and would also be immutable, which is often a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You sure can.  Try something like this:

```
Dim PR As New Dictionary(Of String, IEnumerable(Of String))
PR.Add("Hour2", {elements_PR(4), "1"})
```

Comment: I can't get it to work either. I tried changing the declaration and add the following: PR.Add("Hour1", {"",""}). But it gives the error: Comma, ')' or valid expression continuation expected.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing a parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you could create a class representing the price and the time offset. Therefore, you could do something like `PR.Add("Hour2", instanceOfClass)`.

Depending on the meaning of the description in your situation, you could even include it in your class. It would allow you to use another approach with a `List(Of YourClass)` containing a list of items with the description, the price and the time offset. To retrieve an item by "key", you could then use some Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - yes. Assuming the following was declared somewhere:

```
Dim elements_PR(4) As String : elements_PR(4) = "Hello"
Dim PR As New Dictionary(Of String, String())
```

You can either do:

```
PR.Add("Hour2", {elements_PR(4), "1"})
```

or

```
Dim pr_val() As String = {elements_PR(4), "1"}
PR.Add("Hour1", pr_val)
```