# How to access particular element in array value of Dictionary

Tags: arrays, vb.net, dictionary

I have created a Dictionary to which I add a key/value, where the value is an array. Now I want to display each element of the value array in a particular cell of a table - how do I reference each element of the value, when the value is referenced simply using the Dictionary's key?

I found these two threads, but neither was helpful in this regard:

[Dictionary containing an array of strings as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272521/dictionary-containing-an-array-of-strings-as-value)

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/555552/how-do-i-create-a-key-and-values-dictionarve-creat.html#

Thank you!

Comment: You have to show more of what you have already tried and also explain your requirement and the issue better since it is not that clear. In what way were those links not helpful? You question is currently not answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to loop through each item in the dictionary:

```
Dim foo = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
For Each key In foo.Keys
  Dim value = foo(key)
  'use key and value as needed
Next
```